How to calculate required gate resistance
I want to limit the rise and fall times of a MOSFET with a gate resistor to prevent large EMI. My calculation is as below:
VDS = 24;
VGS = 12; % driving gate-soruce voltage

Ron = 0.0029; % On resistance at operating point
tr = 30*10^-9; % desired rise time
tf = 30*10^-9; % desired fall time
Qtotal = 17*10^-9; % total gate charge at operating point obtained from datasheet (depends on: VDS, VGS)

Ig = Qtotal/tr % Required Gate Current
Cg = Qtotal/VGS; % Gate capacitance at operating point
RG = tr/(5*Cg)

In this calculation, I thought of a RC circuit at the gate in which the capacitor charges in 5 time constants. I found RG as 4.2ohm. I know this includes internal resistance of the MOSFET too which is not written in the datasheet oddly. Is my thinking correct?
Gate driver: FAN3111ESX
MOSFET: IAUC80N04S6N036ATMA1

30 ns rise and fall times still are fast enough to generate a lot of EMI.  What are the gate signal frequency and minimum pulse width?  Also, what is the peak drain current?

Gate signal frequency is 1kHz, peak drain current is 4A. Minimum pulse with is 1/255 of 1/1kHz signal which is -> 4 microseconds. Also I would like to know If I need to bypass gate resistor with a diode for turn off and add a drain-source RCD snubber.

Your calculation is a little naïve without properly taking into account the drain source voltage that is being switched. The Qtotal figure in the data sheet is for when the drain source voltage is 32 volts but, your particular requirement is 24 volts.
I recommend that you use a simulation tool to see the problem for yourself. It should, with a decent model of your MOSFET, take into account the internal gate resistance too.

The difference between 8V and 32V is small and I don't have to match an exact timing, it is just for EMI and not some clock signal. So I thought I could assume a point somewhere around 32V curve.

@CaveScientist your basic question was this: Is my thinking correct? and, I have given an answer. If you want to compromise on "the ideal" that's up to you and not up to me. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

@CaveScientist did you take any notice of my last comment at all?

The answer to my question was Rgate = (VGS-Vpleteau)/Ig. Ig being Qtotal at operating point divided by chosen rise time. It was that simple and instead, you started to humiliate me for no reason. I gave you more details about my design and I told you how important was the precision, I haven't said your methods are wrong. Pls just: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxB-qj4WPn4&ab_channel=ElizabethWhite

@CaveScientist if you have an answer that suits your question then I highly recommend that you you post a formal answer and mark that answer as accepted. This is normal practice for stack exchange. Other than that my answer is the only record that your question has been answered. Think of other folk coming to this post in the future and help them with the best answer. As for your humiliation, I suggest that you flag what I've said to moderators.
